# VirtualBox Ubuntu screen resolution set to 640x400

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I KNOW many people have had this problem before. However, no solution which I have read (and I have read a lot of them) has worked completely. Installing "guest additions" didn't do anything, after i did `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms`. Am I missing something?

BTW, the only solution which kind of worked was enabling 3D acceleration, which made the screen resolution 4:3 (not 16:9). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Using Windows 10, Virtual Box 5.1.26, After trying almost all solutions and documenting them, Finally the following worked.

 1. Close The Virtual Box
 2. Change the maximum values for virtual box under File > Preferences > Display to Hint, 1366, 768;
 2. Go to C:\Users\{username}\.VirtualBox. Replace {username} with the logged in user
 3. Open VirtualBox.xml in an editor and append
   <ExtraDataItem name="CustomVideoMode1" value="1366x768x32"/>
  After 
    <ExtraData>
 4. Go to C:\Users\{username}\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu
 5. Open Ubuntu.vbox (Replace Ubuntu with the name of your virtual machine) in an editor and append
 <ExtraDataItem name="CustomVideoMode1" value="1366x768x32"/>
  After 
    <ExtraData>
 
 6. Close the editor and start the Virtual Box.
 7. Once Ubuntu starts, go to terminal type and change to root
    sudo vi /etc/default/grub
 8. Locate 
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
 9. Modify it to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyper_fb:1366x768x32"
 10. Close the file and run sudo update-grub
 11. Reboot the virtual machine instance.
```

Answer (score -1):

WOW. I just reinstalled guest additions. AND IT WORKED. FINALLY.